# Escape \n in JSON_ENCODE output

Tags: php, json

So i try to add new record to my JSON file but when i encode files i get bunch of `\` and `\n`. How can i remove those?

JSON

```
{
    "clients": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Name",
            "description": "XXX",
            "services": [
                {
                    "name": "dddd",
                    "host": "ddddddd",
                    "login": "ddddd",
                    "password": "ddddd"
                },
                {
                  "name": "dddd",
                  "host": "ddddddd",
                  "login": "ddddd",
                  "password": "ddddd"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

PHP

```
  $inp = file_get_contents('app/keyring.json');
  $tempArray = json_decode($inp);
  $data = '{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "dddd ddd",
    "description": "ddd"
  }';

  array_push($tempArray->clients, $data);
  $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  file_put_contents('app/keyring.json', $jsonData);
```

And This results in:

```
"{\n    \"id\": 5,\n    \"name\": \"dddd ddd\",\n    \"description\": \"ddd\"\n  }"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing a string to your array, instead of an object. It's getting double escaped so that when the file is parsed it will still be a string, because that's what you encoded. Use this instead:

```
$data = json_decode('{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "dddd ddd",
  "description": "ddd"
}');

array_push($tempArray->clients, $data);
```

or, if you're actually building the object in PHP and not getting it as JSON from somewhere else, you can do this:

```
$data = (object)[
  'id' => 5,
  'name' => 'dddd ddd',
  'description' => 'ddd',
];

array_push($tempArray->clients, $data);
```